# A python function to return smallest_multiple

Tags: python, arrays, function

I have been struggling with this problem and don't know where to begin.

Write a Python function called smallest_multiple that takes an array of positve whole numbers as an input. The function must compute and return the smallest whole number that can be divided by each number in the input array without a remainder.

Comment: Do you know how to find the smallest multiple on paper?

Comment: Dude, you have to work it on yourself first and provide your trials and we can help you from there. I know, it's difficult at first, but you will get there eventually. Try to solve it on paper first, write the steps one by one and make it as simple as you can. Then try to write the code. If it fails, we can help you figure out why and how to improve it.